How can I write the contents of one shapefile column to a text file?
I have the Python code below. I would like to write all the names in the name column to a text file. I am able to print it to screen, but this prints only a few rows.
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file("../Shapefiles/geoBoundaries-LSO-ADM2-all/geoBoundaries-LSO-ADM2.shp")
header = ["shapeName"]
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns = header)

df.to_csv('output.csv', columns = header)

This question is similar to: How to write specific columns of a dataframe to a CSV?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks I will look at that answer. I spent the whole day looking for an answer and did not see this one.
